# Firebase Storage ref and getDownloadURL are not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, download, firebase-storage

I'm developing a Vue.js app and I've been trying to download documents from the Firebase Storage, I've read the [Firebase download documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#web-version-9_1) and followed their instructions but for some reason, every time I try to download a document, I still get the same errors in the terminal: "*TypeError: ref is not a function*" or "*TypeError: getDownloadURL is not a function*" if I take the *ref* out of the code. I've seen some questions which are basically the same as mine but I couldn't find a solution for my problem. The code below is in the index.js file of my Vue.js app.

```
const { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } = require('firebase-admin/storage')

app.get('/downloadDocument', (request, response) => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    const storage = getStorage()

    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, request.query.documentURL)).then((url) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = (event) => {
            const blob = xhr.response;
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }).catch((err) => {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'storage/object-not-found':
                alert(`File doesn't exist`)
                break;
            case 'storage/unauthorized':
                alert(`User doesn't have permission to access the object`)
                break;
            case 'storage/canceled':
                alert(`User canceled the upload`)
                break;
            case 'storage/unknown':
                alert(`Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response`)
                break;
        }
    })
    response.send('done')
})
```

As you can see, my code is basically the same as the Firebase documentation, it seems it isn't importing *ref* and *getDownloadURL* but for some reason, it is importing *getStorage*.

Thanks for the help beforehand!

Comment: Firebase Web SDK is different than the Admin SDK. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Isn't `ref` to import from `vue`?

Comment: I'm following what the firebase documentation is telling me to do, in this case, it's showing in the examples ref being imported from firebase, I've tried to use firebase/storage but it said it couldn't find it. This is my first project using firebase, so I'm more than happy to try any ideas.